# Display custom message when constraint is violated PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, constraints, custom-exceptions

I'm writing a pl/sql procedure. I've got a constraint on a column which doesn't allow values below 0 and above 500. I need to display a custom message if this constraint is violated (eg. "ID out of range"). Currently this is the exception and also the output in getting. There is another procedure that is outputting the error, hence the use raise_applcation_error.

Exception

```
when VALUE_ERROR then
raise_application_error(-20002, 'Customer ID out of range');
```

Error Message

```
"ORA-20000: ORA-02290: check constraint (s5849497.CK_ID_RANGE) violated"
```

What I would like

```
"ORA-20000: Customer ID out or range"
```

Here is the whole block if it helps

```
set serveroutput on;

---------------------------------------------------------------
alter table customer
add constraint ck_id_range
check (custid > 0 and custid < 500);
---------------------------------------------------------------

create or replace procedure ADD_CUSTOMER_TO_DB(pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) as

begin
    insert into customer
    values (pcustid,pcustname,0,'OK');
exception
when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Duplicate customer ID');
when VALUE_ERROR then
  raise_application_error(-20002, 'Customer ID out of range');
when others then
  raise_application_error(-20000, SQLERRM);
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: The error message output is not the one I want. so I'm assuming my exception (currently VALUE_ERROR) needs to change to something else in order to show my custom error message. I just don't know what that exception should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're getting an ORA-02290 error. The way to catch this in an exception handler is to declare and initialize an exception for the particular error code (in this case, -2290) and then use your custom exception in the handler:

```
create or replace procedure ADD_CUSTOMER_TO_DB(pcustid number,
                                               pcustname varchar2)
as
  eCheck_constraint_violated  EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(eCheck_constraint_violated, -2290);
begin
    insert into customer
    values (pcustid,pcustname,0,'OK');
exception
when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Duplicate customer ID');
when eCheck_constraint_violated then
  raise_application_error(-20002, 'Customer ID out of range');
when others then
  raise_application_error(-20000, SQLERRM);
end;
```

As you'll see above, I just replaced VALUE_ERROR with the newly-defined exception.

If by chance the error you're getting is not -2290, just put the error you're seeing in `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` invocation above instead of -2290.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I'm getting a compiled error saying echeck_constraint_violated must be declared. I've tried copying your code but that didn't work either

Comment: Move the exception declaration into the procedure, as shown above, or create a package to hold your exception declarations and initializations. Share and enjoy.